# Convert vector<Rect> OpenCV to vector<vector<float>> in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to convert the `vector Rect` datatype to `vector vector float` to use non maximum suppression on the vector. vector contains rectangle points of faces. I want to apply `nms` as seen here:[Non Maximum Suppression](https://github.com/martinkersner/non-maximum-suppression-cpp/blob/master/example.cpp).

When trying to compile I get following error:

**

```
undefined reference to `nms(std::vector<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > > const&, float const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**

I dont know why it is giving the `nms` function 2x `vector vector float`?
Thanks for help!

```
   vector<Rect> apply_pre_filters(vector<Rect>faces_vector){


    // Non Max Suppression
    float threshold = 0.5;
    vector<vector<float>> faces_vector_float_container;
    cout << "original vector size" << faces_vector.size() << endl;

    for (int i=0; i < faces_vector.size(); i++) {
        vector<int> faces_vector_int = {faces_vector[i].tl().x,faces_vector[i].tl().y,faces_vector[i].br().x, faces_vector[i].br().y};
        vector<float> faces_vector_float(faces_vector_int.begin(), faces_vector_int.end());

        faces_vector_float_container.push_back(faces_vector_float);
    }

    cout << "modified vector size" << faces_vector_float_container.size() << endl;
    vector<Rect> filtered_faces_vector = nms(faces_vector_float_container, threshold);

    // Change Faces detected flag
    if(faces_vector.size() > 0){
        faces_detected = true;
    }else{
        faces_detected = false;
    }

    return faces_vector;
}
```

Comment: If you want to convert `vector<Rect>` to `vector<vector<float>>`, why don't you take the Mat of the Rect (bounding box but still a Mat) and convert it to a `list` (you could also convert it to a vector)? You could populate the vector from the Rect using [Rect.tl()](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Rect.html#tl()) and [Rect.br()](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Rect.html#br())

Comment: Did you forget to compile the implementation of `nms` and link it with your code?

Comment: The error is a linking error, this means that you are including a .h file with a function, you use the function, but the compiled .cpp file is not being linked to the code. You should write how are you compiling it to spot what you are missing.

Comment: I am using Clion and included the two files. It should actually compile it automatically. If I look at the definition of the function `nms` it takes `std::vector<cv::Rect> nms(const std::vector<std::vector<float>> &,
                          const float &);` My error says I am passing vector float 2x? Or am I wrong. I am using this lib: https://github.com/martinkersner/non-maximum-suppression-cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the `nms` files into the `CMakeFileList.txt` `SOURCE_FILES()`. It seems to work now.